# myView.getHitRect() returns coordinates in realation to parent. How to get them in relation to the grandparent?

Tags: android

I am using following code to create touch delegate of the view. Problem is that the view which clickable area I want to increase is inside of very narrow LinearLayout. So below code can increase clickable area of my view, but only in the scope of my narrow LinearLayout. I would like to pass to this function not parent but grandparent of myView (myView.getParent().getParent()). It's a RelativeLayout which has space for bigger clickable area. But then touchRect will be pointing in wrong place and my TouchDelegate will be position incorrectly..

Because: delegate.getHitRect(touchRect); returns position in relation to parent, not grandparent (or parent of parent).

```
public static Runnable getTouchDelegateAction(final View delegate, final View parent, final int topPadding, final int bottomPadding, final int leftPadding,
        final int rightPadding) {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // Construct a new Rectangle and let the Delegate set its values
            Rect touchRect = new Rect();
            delegate.getHitRect(touchRect);

            // Modify the dimensions of the Rectangle
            // Padding values below zero are replaced by zeros
            touchRect.top -= Math.max(0, topPadding);
            touchRect.bottom += Math.max(0, bottomPadding);
            touchRect.left -= Math.max(0, leftPadding);
            touchRect.right += Math.max(0, rightPadding);


            // Now we are going to construct the TouchDelegate
            TouchDelegate touchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(touchRect, delegate);

            // And set it on the parent
            parent.setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
        }
    };
}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If somebody had similar problem, then here is a solution which I found. The difference is flag bindToGrandparent which can be set in order to put delegate to grandparent of clickable view.

```
public static Runnable getTouchDelegateAction(final View delegate, final boolean bindToGrandparent, final int topPadding,
        final int bottomPadding, final int leftPadding, final int rightPadding) {
    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            View parent = (View) delegate.getParent();
            View grandparent = (View) parent.getParent();

            // Construct a new Rectangle and let the Delegate set its values
            Rect touchRect = new Rect();
            delegate.getHitRect(touchRect);

            if (bindToGrandparent) {
                touchRect.top += parent.getTop();
                touchRect.left += parent.getLeft();
                touchRect.bottom += parent.getTop();
                touchRect.right += parent.getLeft();
            }

            // Modify the dimensions of the Rectangle
            // Padding values below zero are replaced by zeros
            touchRect.top -= Math.max(0, topPadding);
            touchRect.bottom += Math.max(0, bottomPadding);
            touchRect.left -= Math.max(0, leftPadding);
            touchRect.right += Math.max(0, rightPadding);

            // Now we are going to construct the TouchDelegate
            TouchDelegate touchDelegate = new TouchDelegate(touchRect, delegate);

            // And set it on the parent
            if (bindToGrandparent) {
                grandparent.setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
            } else {
                parent.setTouchDelegate(touchDelegate);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It should be used as follow:

```
grandparentView.post(FuncHelper.getTouchDelegateAction(ivFavorite, true, 30, 30, 30, 30));
```

It's important that procedure should be posted to grandparent of the view.

or:

```
parentView.post(FuncHelper.getTouchDelegateAction(ivFavorite, false, 30, 30, 30, 30));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to create touch delegate of your view in relation to a grandparent, or even a grand grand grandparent, you could add just one line to your code:

`((ViewGroup)parent).offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(delegate, touchRect);`

So the final code could looks like that:

```
public static Runnable getTouchDelegateAction(final View delegate, final View parent, 
                                              final int topPadding, final int bottomPadding, 
                                              final int leftPadding, final int rightPadding) {

    return new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Rect touchRect = new Rect();
            delegate.getHitRect(touchRect);

            // Modify the dimensions of the Rectangle
            // Padding values below zero are replaced by zeros
            touchRect.top -= Math.max(0, topPadding);
            touchRect.bottom += Math.max(0, bottomPadding);
            touchRect.left -= Math.max(0, leftPadding);
            touchRect.right += Math.max(0, rightPadding);

            // calculates the relative coordinates to the parent
            ((ViewGroup) parent).offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(delegate, touchRect);
            parent.setTouchDelegate(new TouchDelegate(touchRect, delegate));
        }
    };
}
```

[Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(android.view.View,%20android.graphics.Rect)) you can find official documentation.